# Continuity of real and imaginary parts in $ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C $

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Let  $ \ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C $ be a continous function.
Prove that the real and imaginary parts of $\ f$ are also continous.

I just learned about the $\epsilon \ \delta$ - definition, so my first approach was to apply the definition of it, to show continuity for Re(z):

$\forall \epsilon\gt 0 \ \exists \ \delta \ \forall  \ \vert Re(z)-Re(z_0)\vert \lt  \delta : \vert \ f(Re(z)) - f(Re(z_0))\vert\lt \epsilon$, with $f(Re(z))=Im(z) $ and $f(Re(z_0))= Im(z_0)$ ?

If that is correct, I don't know how to continue and apply any sort of equivalencies between those parts. Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct, the variable is real, not complex, so there is no $\text{Re}(z)-\text{Re}(z_{0})$.

Rather, let $f(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$. Now observe that $|u(t)-u(t_{0})|\leq|f(t)-f(t_{0})|$, now continuity applies to $f$ at $t=t_{0}$ we have for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for all $t$ with $|t-t_{0}|<\delta$, then $|f(t)-f(t_{0})|<\epsilon$, so $|u(t)-u(t_{0})|<\epsilon$.

Similar reasoning applies to $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=a(x)+ib(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and fix some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$.
You know that:

$$(\forall\epsilon>0)\,(\exists \delta>0)\,(\forall x \text{ with } 0<|x-x_0|<\delta)\,\,\,\,\, |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

Now, observe that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon\iff |f(x)-f(x_0)|^2<\epsilon^2$ and

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|^2={\left(a(x)-a(x_0)\right)}^2+{\left(b(x)-b(x_0)\right)}^2$$

It follows that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon \implies {\left(a(x)-a(x_0)\right)}^2<\epsilon^2 \iff |a(x)-a(x_0)|<\epsilon$, and similarly for $|b(x)-b(x_0)|$.